# PHP if (not multiple values) not working?

Tags: php

I have simple bit of code I want to to use to exit the script if a variable does not match 5 different values. I can only get it to work with one. the script keeps echoing "unknown request" even when the URL variable matches.

```
//Make sure the value of the variable matches one of the variables in the URL.
if($category !== ('food' || 'drink' || 'etc.'))
{echo "unknown request.";
exit();
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compare each value.  Also, you want AND `&&`:

```
if($category !== 'food' && $category !== 'drink' && $category !==  'etc.')
```

Or use an array:

```
if(!in_array($category, array('food', 'drink', 'etc.'))
```